# spring amqp-outbound gateway to produce reply from a different thead (Like jms-outbound gateway)

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-amqp

**Problem statement:**

Spring amqp-outbound gateway to produce reply from a different thread (Like jms-outbound gateway, having different queue, correlate the request/response using correlation key).

Unable to correlate the message with this example.

**Spring integration**

```
    <int:gateway id="outboundGateway" service-interface="com.amqp.outbound.gateway.OutboundGateway"     
                        default-reply-channel="defaultReplyChannel" >
        <int:method name="process"   request-channel="inboundRequestChannel"/>
    </int:gateway>

    <int:channel id="defaultReplyChannel"/>
    <int:channel id="inboundRequestChannel"/>
    <int:channel id="enrichedInboundRequestChannel"/>
    <int:channel id="processAuthRequestChannel"/>
    <int:channel id="postProcessorChannel"/>

    <int:chain input-channel="inboundRequestChannel" output-channel="enrichedInboundRequestChannel">
        <int:service-activator id="serviceActivator"
                       ref="ouboundService"  method="createRequest"/>
    </int:chain>

    <int-amqp:outbound-gateway id="outboundGtwyId" header-mapper="headerMapper"
                        request-channel="enrichedInboundRequestChannel"
                        reply-channel="defaultReplyChannel"
                        amqp-template="template" 
                        reply-timeout="30000" 
                        exchange-name="request_exchange" 
                        routing-key="request_exchange_queue"/>

    <int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter id="amqpMessageDriven"  queue-names="request_queue" 
                                 connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"  channel="processAuthRequestChannel"/>

    <int:service-activator id="serviceActivator"
                       ref="ouboundService" input-channel="processAuthRequestChannel" output-channel="postProcessorChannel"
                       method="processRequest"/>

    <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter amqp-template="template" channel="postProcessorChannel" 
            header-mapper="headerMapper" exchange-name="reply_exchange" routing-key="reply_exchange_queue"/>

    <bean id="headerMapper" class="org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper"/>
```

**Config**

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate template(ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory){
    final RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    template.setQueue("reply_queue");
    return template;
}



@Bean
public Binding binding(){
    return BindingBuilder.bind(this.queue()).to(this.exchange()).with("request_exchange_queue");
}

@Bean
public DirectExchange exchange(){
    return new DirectExchange("request_exchange");
}

@Bean
public Queue queue(){
    return new Queue("request_queue", true, false, true);
}

@Bean
public Binding bindingReply(){
    return BindingBuilder.bind(this.queue()).to(this.exchange()).with("reply_exchange_queue");
}

@Bean
public DirectExchange exchangeReply(){
    return new DirectExchange("reply_exchange");
}


@Bean
public Queue replyQueue(){
    return new Queue("reply_queue", true, false, true);
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public final class OuboundService {


    public Message createRequest(String message){
        System.out.println("Inside createRequest : "+ message);
        final String transactionId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        final Message builtMessage = MessageBuilder.withBody(message.getBytes())
                .setContentType(MessageProperties.CONTENT_TYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)
                .setHeader(AmqpHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, transactionId)
                .build();
        return builtMessage;
    }


    public Message processRequest(Message message){
        System.out.println("Inside process Request : "+ new String(message.getBody()));
        System.out.println("Header values : "+message.getMessageProperties().getHeaders());
        final Message result = MessageBuilder.withBody("Successful".getBytes()).copyProperties(message.getMessageProperties())
                                .copyHeaders(message.getMessageProperties().getHeaders()).build();
        return result;
    }

}
```

**Error:**

org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyRequiredException: No reply produced by handler 'outboundGtwyId', and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true.

**GitHub source code (Resolved Solution)**

https://github.com/kingkongprab/spring-amqp-outbound-gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  correlation is done in the Spring AMQP as well. See its `RabbitTemplate#sendAndRecevie()` for more info. Also there is a good documentation on the matter in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#request-reply).

Spring Integration  with its `AbstractAmqpOutboundEndpoint` and `AmqpInboundGateway` implementations provides out-of-the-box request-reply correlation solution. If you are not able to use `AmqpInboundGateway` on the server side, you should ensure the `correlationId` transfer from received request to the reply to send back. Yes, you can use dedicated exchange for replies and that is what supported by the `RabbitTemplate#setQueue()` to wait for replies on the client, outbound side. But that still isn't going to work without proper `correlation` transferring. Also see https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-message-headers for the info how headers (including `correlationId`) are mapped in Spring Integration.

**UPDATE**

Thank you for sharing your application.

Well, now I see several problems:

1. You are definitely missing the `replyQueue` binding:

   ```
   @Bean
   public Binding bindingReply(){
       return BindingBuilder.bind(this.replyQueue()).to(this.exchangeReply()).with("reply_exchange_queue");
   }
   ```
2. `RabbitTemplate` must use `setReplyAddress()`. You have to configure `MessageListenerContainer` for the `reply_queue` and have `RabbitTemplate` as a listener:

   ```
   @Bean
   public RabbitTemplate template(ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory){
       final RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(rabbitConnectionFactory);
       template.setReplyAddress(replyQueue().getName());
       return template;
   }

   @Bean
   public MessageListenerContainer replyContainer(RabbitTemplate template) {
       SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
       container.setConnectionFactory(template.getConnectionFactory());
       container.setQueues(replyQueue());
       container.setMessageListener(template);
       return container;
   }
   ```
3. Your `OuboundService` with `org.springframework.amqp.core.Message` manipulation is useless. The Channel Adapters don't know about this type of `payload` and your custom `Message` just becomes as a serialized `body` of another `org.springframework.amqp.core.Message`. I have changed it to this and everything works well:

   ```
   public String createRequest(String message){
       System.out.println("Inside createRequest : "+ message);
       return message;
   }


   public Message processRequest(Message message){
       System.out.println("Inside process Request : " + message);
       return message;
   }
   ```

Anyway I suggest you to rethink your design and come back to the `AmqpInboundGateway`.

BTW in the final solution you don't need to care about any `correlation`. The Framework does that for you automatically.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157947/discussion-on-answer-by-artem-bilan-spring-amqp-outbound-gateway-to-produce-repl).