# Spring AMQP custom message correlation using an identifier generated by the app

Tags: spring-amqp

Spring AMQP custom message correlation using an identifier generated by the app for the outbound gateway using spring integration.

We have a requirement where we need to correlate messages for outbound gateway with an id generated by app, in which actual processing of the messages would happen in external system and the response for the request will come as post from the external system, so we cannot rely on amqp_correlation data.

If you provide the steps for this that will be great.

**Solution Tried**

1. Set the correlation key in the rabbit template
2. Create Message of type AMQP, set the header name with the correleation key set in the template with some generated value
3. Provide header-mapper in the AMQP outbound gateway for the custom header name

**Result**

Rabbit template was able to map with the custom header, However it generates its own value, Not using the value that was set in the request/reply messages

Comment: Can you explain why the correlationId has to be generated by the app? The template generates its own (and restores the user value) because we must ensure it's unique. If you are using the correlationId to communicate other information to the receiver, can you not use another header for that?

Comment: The actual processing of the message happens in different system by making a rest call. they will again perform a POST call to provide a response to the thread waiting in outbound gateway, so we cannot rely on correleation id generated by template. Yes, I'm trying to use new header parameter to correlate the messages, problem is, the value of the field is not used by the template, it generates it own value which is very difficult to correlate the response.

Comment: "POST call to provide a response to the thread waiting in outbound gateway," How is it related to the AMQP? Consider to use `Aggregator` afterward for custom correlation of such a complex solution. Would be great to see your integration flow, please

Comment: Artem, its same we worked on the issue correlation issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47016080/spring-amqp-outbound-gateway-to-produce-reply-from-a-different-thead-like-jms-o, Think that outbound-channel-adapter input channel is exposed to the gateway that will be getting the response.

Answer (score 1):

Please open a [new feature JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP) for this.

Bear in mind it will be your responsibility to ensure the correlationId is unique.

You might be able to work around it by subclassing the template and overriding `sendToRabbit`; and set up the correlationId there; you would have to save off the template's `correlationId` (ideally in the message in a different header, but perhaps in a `Map`) and have the server return that header too.

```
protected void sendToRabbit(Channel channel, String exchange, String routingKey, boolean mandatory,
        Message message) throws IOException {
    // fix up properties
    super.doSend(...);
}
```

You would also have to override `onMessage()` to restore the proper correlationId for the inbound request.

Comment: Gary, if we build the org.springframework.amqp.core.Message object in the transformer before processing the request in outbound gateway, does the AMQP framework support to populate correlation id using UUID generator?

Comment: No; as I said you need to fix up the message at the last moment (in `sendToRabbit()`). We will need changes to the template to support user-provided correlation. It's not hard to do, we can put it in the next release quite easily; I just need a JIRA issue.

Comment: Ok, All set https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-779, When do think this will be implemented and released?

Comment: Can you add your configuration? The correlationId manipulation is only performed when the template has a reply container (which is not the case here). See my example in the JIRA.